# SecurityConfig [Spring boot version 2.5.x]: api gateway doesn't make redirect/forward to service and always return 401

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to configure an API gateway for filtering and forwarding requests to other services.

But in logs, I see that my filters work and after that nothing happens and as a result, I have a 401 error.

application.properties file for configure routing:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lowerCaseServiceId=true


spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=api-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://api-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api-service/**
```

and also SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            ...
    };

    @Autowired
    private JsonWebTokenParser<Claims> jwtParser;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(jwtParser);

        http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .addFilterAfter(authenticationFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to put the filter before the authorization filter instead of after?

Comment: yes, but the same result, and anyway in case if I don't use filters gateway doesn't forward requests to services